# How to display 'created_time' from facebook api response using php sdk 5

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using php sdk 5 reading all post from my page using the Facebook API.

My problem is just to echo the `created_time` from the response data to no avail.

```
  try {
        // Get a list of pages with you as admin
        $posts_request = $fb->get('/'.$fbpageid.'/feed?fields=id,message,created_time');
        
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo 'Request error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

And here a sample of the response data:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2072715452753496_2089871617704546 
        [message] => sample of post number one 
        [created_time] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2018-02-15 02:39:28.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 1 
            [timezone] => +00:00 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2072715452753496_2082500291775012 
        [message] => sample post number two 
        [created_time] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2018-02-10 10:24:53.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 1 
            [timezone] => +00:00 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2072715452753496_2072717852753256 
        [created_time] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2018-02-03 09:56:16.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 1 
            [timezone] => +00:00 
        ) 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2072715452753496_2072717476086627 
        [created_time] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2018-02-03 09:55:46.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 1 [timezone] => +00:00 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
try {
    // Get a list of pages with you as admin
    $posts_request = $fb->get('/'.$fbpageid.'feed?fields=id,message,created_time'); 

    foreach ($posts_request as $key => $value){
        echo $value['created_time']->format('Y-m-d'); // format your DateTime object 
    }
}
```

this could https://paulund.co.uk/datetime-php